# A class of symmetric functions

Tags: co.combinatorics, generating-functions, closed-form-expressions

When attacking a symmetric problem via an asymmetric method, I encountered the following function: $$U_2(n, m) = \sum_{a = 0}^n\binom na (2^a + 2^{n - a})^m.$$
It is easy to see that this function is in fact symmetric in $n,m$: $$U_2(n, m) = \sum_{a + b = n\\a, b \geq 0}\sum_{c + d = m\\c, d \geq 0}\frac{n!}{a!b!}\frac{m!}{c!d!}2^{ac + bd}.$$

And for more general cases, there are also: 
\begin{eqnarray*}U_3(n, m) &=& \sum_{a = 0}^n\sum_{b = 0}^{n - a}\binom n a\binom{n - a}b(2^a + 2^b + 2^{n - a - b})^m\\ &=& \sum_{a + b + c = n\\a, b, c\geq 0}\sum_{d + e + f = m\\d, e, f\geq0}\frac{n!}{a!b!c!}\frac{m!}{d!e!f!}2^{ad + be + cf}
\end{eqnarray*}
and so on.

> Are these functions known (e.g. with $2$ replaced by some $x$)? Are there any kind of "closed formulas" for them (or some nice generating functions etc.)?

Since every $U_n$ only has two parameters, I hope it might be possible to simplify the sum.

It's funny that when I try to transform them using my usual "exchange summation order" method, I keep getting the same formula with eventually $m, n$ exchanged...

Comment: Another symmetric form:
$$U_2(m,n) = 2^{mn/2} \sum_{a=0}^n \sum_{b=0}^m \binom{n}{a} \binom{m}{b} T_{(n-2a)(m-2b)}(\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{4}),$$
 where $T$ are [Chebyshev polynomials of fist kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).

Comment: This reminds me [OEIS A181230](https://oeis.org/A181230) given by a symmetric double-summation formula, were each of the sums can be evaluated into a closed form but not both at the same time.